# System dependencies as part of a CLI (brew, apt)

Tags: dependencies, shared-libraries, homebrew, packaging, apt

I'd like to release a CLI. However, some of the Python dependencies for the CLI require system dependencies. Namely, the python package `soundfile` requires the shared object library `libsndfile`. I'd like to avoid asking users to install this library on their own.

Is there a way to package or install this library along with my CLI? For example, is there a way to `brew install` or `apt install` these libraries in the brew or apt package? (That seems wrong to me, since users may need sudo). Is there a way to package the libsndfile library in CLI package?

Suggestions or best practices to solve this problem are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: You can probably find some inspirations with lilv https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/main/Formula/lilv.rb